# Fragment Transaction show() does not show fragment on second time

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment inside of a fragment. This setup works fine until you rotate the device. After you rotate the device the inner fragment does not show anymore.

I am calling the .show() method and I have a couple of log statements to display what's going on, and the fragment just doesn't show up after rotation.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code. The issue can be found in the private method displayTab():

```
public static class MyTabsListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener
{
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;
    private final Bundle mArgs;
    private Fragment mFragment;
    private FragmentManager fm;
    private Fragment fragmentJobListDetails;
    private Fragment fragmentTrends;

    public MyTabsListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz, FragmentManager fragmentManager) 
    {
        this(activity, tag, clz, null,fragmentManager);
    }

    public MyTabsListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz, Bundle args, FragmentManager fragmentManager) 
    {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
        mArgs = args;
        fm = fragmentManager;


        // Check to see if we already have a fragment for this tab, probably
        // from a previously saved state.  If so, deactivate it, because our
        // initial state is that a tab isn't shown.
        mFragment = mActivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);
        if (mFragment != null && !mFragment.isDetached()) 
        {
            FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.hide(mFragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) 
    {
        displayTab(tab, ft);    
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) 
    {
        if (mFragment != null) 
        {
            ft.hide(mFragment);
            //ft.remove(mFragment);

        }           
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) 
    {
        displayTab(tab, ft);
    }

    private void displayTab(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
        fragmentJobListDetails = mActivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("jobDetails");
        fragmentTrends = mActivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("trends");

        if (fragmentJobListDetails != null && !fragmentJobListDetails.isDetached()) 
        {
            ft.hide(fragmentJobListDetails);
        }

        if (mFragment == null) 
        {
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName(), mArgs);
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } 
        else 
        {
            if (mFragment == fragmentTrends)
            {
                System.out.println("fragments are equal");
                System.out.println("equal. Fragment added? = " + mFragment.isAdded());
                System.out.println("equal. Fragment detached? = " + mFragment.isDetached());
                System.out.println("equal. Fragment visible? = " + mFragment.isVisible());

                ft.show(fragmentTrends);

                System.out.println("equal. Fragment added? = " + mFragment.isAdded());
                System.out.println("equal. Fragment detached? = " + mFragment.isDetached());
                System.out.println("equal. Fragment visible? = " + mFragment.isVisible());

            }

            ft.show(mFragment);
        }   
    }
}// end MyTabsListener
```

And here's the output of my logs, after rotation:

```
11-25 09:17:24.895: I/System.out(14605): mFragment = TrendsPagerHolder{427a94a8 #1 id=0x1020002 trends}
11-25 09:17:24.895: I/System.out(14605): fragments are equal
11-25 09:17:24.895: I/System.out(14605): equal. Fragment added? = true
11-25 09:17:24.895: I/System.out(14605): equal. Fragment detached? = false
11-25 09:17:24.895: I/System.out(14605): equal. Fragment visible? = false
11-25 09:17:24.895: I/System.out(14605): equal. Fragment added? = true
11-25 09:17:24.895: I/System.out(14605): equal. Fragment detached? = false
11-25 09:17:24.895: I/System.out(14605): equal. Fragment visible? = false
```

Thanks!

Comment: when you rotate your device the activity restarts. Which means your onCreate function is called again!

Comment: Yes, but what does that have to do? all of the other fragments listed on other tabs show up, except this one

Comment: do you need the device to be able to change orientation?

Comment: yes, for specific fragments/tabs only though. And when it changes, it displays a different view

Comment: call commit() after show();

Comment: I get a runtime error when I call commit saying commit has already been called

Comment: Can you share your code,related with the line below,         mFragment = mActivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);     Either XML or JAVA class whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is wrong with the entire operation, but I use the following lines and it always works:

```
MyDialogFragment dialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment(data);
dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), key);
```

Note that MyDialogFragment has two constructors one excepts the data the other is default (empty)

using the saveState and restoreState allow you to save the dialog state.

I hope this will work for you as well.

Comment: how would you save it in the bundle though?

Comment: not sure what do you mean... create the Fragment with a data object, if you need to save the state then override the savestate callback, makesure you have a default constructor so restoring(instantiating via reflection by the os) the dialog would be successful, in one of the callback that comes with the saved state bundle you can restore it... I think it is the onViewCreated

Answer (score -1):

You need to override the default execution of configuration changes. You can do this by using the `configChanges` attribute of the activity tag in AndroidManifest. Read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).

Comment: Don't use configChanges. Read here: https://speakerdeck.com/cyrilmottier/deep-dive-into-android-state-restoration

Comment: @EGHDK, any suggestion on what I should do then?

Comment: Thanks, but the setRetainInstance(true); doesn't really change anything